# Get an element created by a script in react without ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ref

I have a chat button created by a script (zendesk chat). It generate an iframe in the page with the ID "launcher".
I'm using Nextjs and Im trying to get this element but I cannot attach a ref since I've not the code.
I am digging the web for a solution and I have tried something like this (in the footer component because it is on all pages and I am able to figure out which page I am on):

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    function checkElExist() {
      if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
        const el = document.querySelector('#launcher');
        if (!isSingleVehiclePage) {
          console.log('NOT VEHICLE', el);
          if (el) {
            el.classList.remove('inVehicle');
            el.classList.add('notInVehiclePage');
          }
        } else {
          console.log('IN VEHICLE', el);
          if (el) {
            el.classList.remove('notInVehiclePage');
            el.classList.add('inVehicle');
          }
        }
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', checkElExist);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('load', checkElExist);
  }, [isSingleVehiclePage]);
```

I don't know if is the right solution. It kinda works but sometimes the element is null especially when I land on that specific page from an external link (not when I navigate the site).
Is it possibile to get this element? My goal is to add/remove a class to it according to specific pages.

Thanks

EDIT: I dont know if it is relevant, but in the html the iframe is out of my "__next" div. In the pic below, I circled the __next div, the footer div (where my useLayoutEffect code is executed) and the iframe I want to get.

[image: html code structure]

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**
I use a function that runs recursively every 1000ms. If it can't find the element in 9000ms, it stops.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    waitForElementToDisplay(
      '#launcher',
      function (el: any) {
        checkElExist(el);
      },
      1000,
      9000
    );
    function checkElExist(el: any) {
      if (!isSingleVehiclePage) {
        console.log('NOT VEHICLE', el);
        el.classList.remove('inVehicle');
        el.classList.add('notInVehiclePage');
      } else {
        console.log('IN VEHICLE', el);
        el.classList.remove('notInVehiclePage');
        el.classList.add('inVehicle');
      }
    }
  }, [isSingleVehiclePage]);

function waitForElementToDisplay(
    selector: string,
    callback: any,
    checkFrequencyInMs: number,
    timeoutInMs: number
  ) {
    const startTimeInMs = Date.now();
    (function loopSearch() {
      if (document && document.querySelector(selector) != null) {
        console.log('found');
        const element = document.querySelector(selector);
        callback(element);
        return;
      } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
          if (timeoutInMs && Date.now() - startTimeInMs > timeoutInMs) return;
          loopSearch();
        }, checkFrequencyInMs);
      }
    })();
  }
```